# React Redux - 401 - unauthorized - missing headers in Request Headers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I am having an issue with React Redux throwing 401 - unauthorized error.

I'm trying to get service API data with authorization headers, but getting 401 - Unauthorized error and the response is Missing Request Headers.

I have included "headers" section in the action and provided "Content-Type" and "Authorization" with jwt token.

I am not sure what I am missing.

Could anyone please help me with this issue?

Here is my code for Action:

```
export const getItem = () => {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    debugger;
    dispatch({
      type: 'API_REQUEST',
      options: {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
          'Authorization': 'jwt eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6IjIxZjE0M2U3LTlhMzEtNGIwNi1hMzJhLTY0NDM2NTFiMTUxZSIsImRhdGUiOiJ5eXl5LTM3LVdlOjExOjM3OjE3IiwiaWF0IjoxNTQzNDA1MDM3fQ.G0h1kh5sunxpKNcFdb5s54c0hKiXyPJhRywbR5-_sk0'
        },
        endpoint: `http://18.222.137.195:3000/v1/item?offset=0`,
        actionTypes: {
          success: types.GET_ITEM_SUCCESS,
          loading: types.GET_ITEM_LOADING,
          error: types.GET_ITEM_ERROR
        }
      }
    });
  };
};
```

Here is my code for Reducer:

```
import * as types from '../actions/registerItemTypes';

export const initialState = {
  getItem: {}
};

const registerItem = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {


    case types.GET_ITEM_LOADING:
      return { ...state, loading: true, data: null };

    case types.GET_ITEM_SUCCESS:
      return { ...state, loading: false, getItem: action.data};

    case types.GET_ITEM_ERROR:
      return { ...state, loading: false, error: action.data};

    default: {
      return state;
    }
  }
}

export default registerItem;
```

Comment: Probably you need to pass token like `'Authorization': 'Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6IjIxZjE0M2U3LTlhMzEtNGIwNi1hMzJhLTY0NDM2NTFiMTUxZSIsImRhdGUiOiJ5eXl5LTM3LVdlOjExOjM3OjE3IiwiaWF0IjoxNTQzNDA1MDM3fQ.G0h1kh5sunxpKNcFdb5s54c0hKiXyPJhRywbR5-_sk0'`

Comment: 1) You've just exposed credentials. Disable them immediately or you'll get pwned. 2) This has nothing to do with React or Redux, you're having a problem accessing your backend (specifically, authenticating with JWT)

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri hello, thank you for your answer. That doesn't seem to solve my issue. Do you know any other solutions that I can try to fix this?